# PLSQL Adding new publisher in publisher table and then adding it to book table where publisher value is null and Displaying it in the given format

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am trying to write a PLSQL block to display details of books along with their Author and Publisher. problem statement is as follow:

1. Insert new publisher 'ttk publisher' into publishers table.
2. Assign this new value in the book table for the records where publisher value is null.
3. Retrive the new records which is newly updated in below format(Use String functions to display only the first 10 letters of column 'Title')

Output format is as follows:

```
BOOKID.............TITLE.............publisher.............Author

639163050...........10 Years o...........Prentice Hall...........Paul Deitel    
330895717...........African Fo...........Prentice Hall...........Tem Nieto
```

Schema Details are given below

```
1.author- authorid, firstname, lastname

2.book- author_id, bookid, publisherid, title

3.publisher- publisherid, publishername
```

Answer (score 0):

That would be something like this. Read comments within code.

```
declare
  l_publisherid   publisher.publisherid%type;
begin
  -- 1. You didn't say how PUBLISHER.PUBLISHER_ID gets its value,
  -- so I'll presume that it is automatically generated, somehow
  -- (identity column or a database trigger)
  insert into publisher (publishername) values ('ttk publisher')
    returning publisherid into l_publisherid;
  
  -- 2. 
  update book b set
    b.publisherid = l_publisherid
    where b.publisherid is null;

  -- 3. Join all 3 tables on appropriate columns. Use a loop to
  -- display ALL books involved. WHERE clause is used to retrieve
  -- books whose PUBLISHERID has just been updated
  for cur_r in 
    (select b.bookid, 
            substr(b.title, 1, 10) title, 
            p.publishername publisher, 
            a.firstname ||' '|| a.lastname author
     from book b join publisher p on p.publisherid = b.publisherid
     join author a on a.authorid = b.author_id
     where p.publisherid = l_publisherid
    )
  loop
    dbms_output.put_line(cur_r.bookid    ||'...'||
                         cur_r.title     ||'...'||
                         cur_r.publisher ||'...'||
                         cur_r.author);
  end loop;                         
end;
/
```

Comment: Hi  thanks, I tried running this same code but its giving an error of ~ no response on stdout ~

Comment: Well, if you posted proper test case (CREATE TABLE and INSERT INTO statements), I/we could test it. Besides, which tool do you use? Did you **enable** dbms_output?

Comment: I am running it on hackerrank

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how it *operates*, never used it.

Answer (score 0):

This is the way it should work for hackerrank:

```
      set serveroutput on
    
    declare
    l_publisherid publisher.publisherid%type;
    begin
    
        insert into publisher values (123, 'TTK Publisher')
        returning publisherid into l_publisherid;
           
        update book b set b.publisherid=l_publisherid
        where b.publisherid is null;
    
      declare
    
      cursor c is
    
        select * from book b
    left join author on authorid=author_id
    left join publisher p on b.publisherid=p.publisherid
    where p.publisherid=l_publisherid;
    
    
     begin
        dbms_output.put_line('BOOKID'||'.............'||'TITLE'||'.............'||'publisher'||'.............'||'Author');
    
      for i in c loop
       dbms_output.put_line(i.bookid||'...........'||substr(i.title,1,10)||'...........'||i.publishername||'...........'||concat(i.firstname||' ',i.lastname));
        end loop;
        END;
END;
/
```